# SENotify - Stack Exchange new question notification (perl/growl)

Tags: app, notifier, growl

### Output/Screenshot

#### Growl notification

Growl on Mac
[image: Mac Growl]
Growl on Windows
[image: Windows Growl]

#### Terminal output

```
$ perl SENotify.pl -s stackoverflow  -r 60 -v

2 question found on serverfault at : Tue Jun 22 21:41:38 2010

Best way to implement Amazon CloudFront for established website
[amazon-s3] [cdn] [cloudfront] (v:2|a:0)
http://www.serverfault.com/questions/153764

Unable to move print spooler on Windows Server 2008R2
[windows-server-2008-r2] [print-server] (v:1|a:0)
http://www.serverfault.com/questions/153765

1 question found on serverfault at : Tue Jun 22 22:01:40 2010

POP3 authentication using email address in Exchange
[exchange] [exchange-2010] [pop3] (v:2|a:0)
http://www.serverfault.com/questions/153770
```

### About

This perl script is a notification tool of new question on Stack Exchange website.
It supports output to terminal (STDOUT) as well as Growl (on both Mac OS X and Windows)

#### License

[GPL v3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)

#### Download

Latest source is available here : http://code.google.com/p/senotify/source/browse/trunk/
Website is here : http://code.google.com/p/senotify/

#### Platform

This is a Perl script, any platform running perl can run it.
If you are looking for a .Net implementation take a look to the [soapi-notify](https://stackapps.com/questions/820) .Net clone

To use it you need Perl and the following Perl module
- JSON
- LWP::UserAgent

You can do so with the following command (sudo is optional)
sudo cpan -i JSON
sudo cpan -i LWP::UserAgent

ActivePerl for Windows comes with both module included
Mac OS X users will have to install JSON module

#### Growl

Mac OS X and Windows users can take advantage of Growl notification.
See http://growl.info/ for Mac users
See http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/ for Windows users

Mac users: in the Growl image disk, install growlnotify located in the Extras direcotry

#### Version

Current version is 0.5

Change in v0.5 are:

- Add tag inclusion filter
- Add verbose mode, need to be enable to see number of question found.

Change in v0.4 are:

- use API v0.9

Change in v0.3 are:

- Improve Growl for Windows output
- Show count value (view/answer) after tag list for a better question visibility
- Add a readme file
- Add usage example

Change in v0.2 are:

- Add proxy support
- Add Windows growl support
- Use API Key
- Provide logo and suppress --image option
- Add question URL to terminal output
- Better query to API
- Show number of new question in terminal output
- Add view count to output
- Support multiple --site argument to monitor many site at once
- Support tag exclusion with --excludetag

### Contact

Author is Jean-Edouard Babin can be contacted at jeb in jeb.com.fr

### Code

Code is written in Perl and is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/senotify/source/browse/trunk/SENotify.pl), you can contribute by sending patch to jeb in jeb.com.fr

Comment: Is there documentation?

Comment: @George Edison I started this today the only documentation available yet is the program help flag

Comment: here is the .net clone. hope you don't mind and hopefully you will get some love spilled over here. ;-)  http://stackapps.com/questions/820/soapi-notify-stack-exchange-new-question-notification-an-unsolicited-net-clon

Comment: radius - after using the app for a day i have some observations that you may be interested in. see http://stackapps.com/questions/820/soapi-notify-stack-exchange-new-question-notification-stay-ahead-of-the-pack/830#830

Comment: @radious +1 very slick. Feature-request: a good packaging for dummies.

Comment: @systempuntoout I don't really see how to make a packaging as it rely on external tools (perl, perl module, growl) but you can use the web version http://stackapps.com/questions/940/

Comment: This may be obvious, but I wanted to add it here in case its not.  You can get it to monitor the new webapps stackexchange site by using 
`perl SENotify.pl -s webapps.stackexchange`

Comment: Yep ! I should load site list on stackauth... patch are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Possible Improvment

Here is what I think good for a next version

- Place the `(v:X|a:X)` part at the end of tag list for a better question visibility <- DONE
- Improve terminal output to refresh `(v:X|a:X)` values of older question (and may be removed answered one from screen) using curse or something like this.

Any comment are welcome

Comment: I like the idea of placing the metric last. Unfortunately i just released v1 that still has them ahead of the title. In the next incremental release I will change this and modify the custom displays. Your windows users can then use the custom displays with your script.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it fails with the following reason:

```
$ perl SENotify.pl -s stackoverflow -r 10 -v
Unable to retrieve data (404 Not Found) at SENotify.pl line 151.
```

Comment: Could you please retry latest version. I forgot to commit the change for the API 1.0