# What real world application does the Stack API have?

Tags: discussion

This is such a noob question, but its simple, so hopefully someone can answer for me please:

If you skill up in the Stack API, what purpose does it serve? What can you do with the API, how can you apply it in real world scenarios?

Examples please. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were a couple of old questions on Meta that had a lot of good ideas.

[What do you want to build with the SO API?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/35723/what-do-you-want-to-build-with-the-so-api)
[What would you want to see in a StackOverflow API?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12224/what-would-you-want-to-see-in-a-stackoverflow-api)

Comment: Clippy: "I noticed you're trying to parse HTML with regular expressions.  Are you sure that's a good idea?"  ;)

Comment: @JL01 - I actually started on one of those last night, but I gave up after struggling with VS's plugin scheme for 4 hours (VS/C# is not my primary development environment).

Answer (score 3):

For some examples, look at the postings under the [apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app) and [library](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library) tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can write applications that leverage the so body of content.

There is a whole 'apps' tab full of 'real-world' examples.

One of my entries is [soapi-notify : Stay ahead of the pack with new question notification V1 release](https://stackapps.com/questions/820)