# App to monitor a beta site for all questions

Tags: discussion, app-request

The only notification app I could find that lets you monitor all questions on a site is [soapi-notify](https://stackapps.com/questions/820/soapi-notify-stay-ahead-of-the-pack-with-new-question-notification-v1-release), but it doesn't let you monitor beta sites. Is there an application that will let me monitor all questions on a beta site, so I can get real time updates?

Comment: By "Monitor" I take it you mean you want an active alert (say an info window or a popup or a sound or something) for each new question?

Comment: @Farseeker: Exactly

Answer (score 1):

I am finishing up the documentation for [Soapi.JS2.](https://stackapps.com/questions/1433). When I finish that tonight I will be updating [soapi-notify](https://stackapps.com/questions/820/soapi-notify-stay-ahead-of-the-pack-with-new-question-notification-v1-release) to provide full coverage.

stackauth did not exist at the time it was written.

I will also add the ability to monitor specific questions so you can pin your questions of interest and watch them as they evolve.

Comment: Will accept when that is complete =P

Comment: early evening tomorrow - likely.

Comment: @Casebash - sorry - the failure of the API throttle to perform to spec is keeping me busy putting out fires. I will get to this ASAP

Comment: @case - ok, i am now building Soapi.Notify2, with the features listed. The introduction of the new features prevent a simply update of the v1 app. eta 2 days.

Comment: @case - I am still on it. am on an earn while you learn, so to speak, journey through some of the subtle aspects of WPF, which is a completely different paradigm than WinForms. getting close.