# Web SENotify - Stack Exchange website new question notification

Tags: app, javascript, website, notifier

### Screenshot

[image: website]

### About

This website is a notification tool of new question on Stack Exchange website.

#### License

Public Domain

#### Download

Download http://senotify.jeb.be/ content (html, css, js from)

#### Platform

Should work in most modern broswer.
Tested in Firefox 3.6.6, Safari 5 and IE 7.

#### Version

Current version is 0.4

Change in v0.4:

- Use API 1.0

Change in v0.3:

- Add inclusise tag filter

Change in v0.2:

- IE7 now working
- Larger notification box
- Display time untill next refresh (site by site)
- Unchecking box cancel notification
- Handle all result even if they are on more than one page

#### Contact

Author is Jean-Edouard Babin can be contacted at jeb in jeb.com.fr

#### Code

Code is written in javascript, it use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with [Gritter](http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/) extension

#### improvement idea

- Do larger notification box <-- Done in v0.2
- Custom refresh time
- Chrome/Safari extension to put notification on current tab
- Show time untill next refresh <-- Done in v0.2
- Exclusive tag filter
- ...

#### Known limitation

- No other way than refresh webpage to cancel notification <-- Done in v0.2
- If there is more than one page of result only first page is handled <-- Done in v0.2
- Not working in IE <-- Done in v0.2

Comment: Your key is very public if you choose to show debug info.

Comment: it's in the source anyway

Comment: Looks good! Please consider listing this on [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I came across this when I was looking for a web-based notifier, and it does the job quite well. The one gripe I had with it is that it doesn't use desktop notifications, and I would have to constantly tab back over if I wanted to see what it came up with.

Anyway, I hacked away at it for a few hours and did a basic implementation of desktop notifications, which works okay as proof of concept. I uploaded it as as an unpacked packaged app for Chrome so it all works self-contained while also being easy enough to merge into your main if you want The way that the notification is displayed is completely in notification.html, so it can be styled with CSS however you like (and, well, edited; it's just regular old XHTML, after all).

http://www.mediafire.com/?wzs0czddibjvqdk

While you can take a look at it just locally extracted, Desktop Notifications as currently implemented in Chrome (16.0.912.75 as of writing) do *not* currently work from local files unless packaged as an app/extension/etc.

If anybody playing along at home actually wants to try it in Chrome for themselves, extract the folder, go to chrome://extensions, check Developer mode, and use the "Load unpacked extension" to load up the folder. The icons are just a very quick so-I-don't-get-sued-for-using-the-Stack-Exchange-Inc.-trademark-logo-placeholder-in-this-program-that-I-was-using-earlier set of images I threw together, and if you like replacing them is as easy as replacing the named files while preserving the file format (PNG) and the dimensions.

Except for the content that is public domain or otherwise previously licensed, all resources in the program are licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License (yes, the same cc-by-sa that all the other user contributions on Stack Exchange are under).